# Entity Framework Code First - Join Composed Key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, firebird, entity-framework-5

- Firebird 2.5
- Entity Framework 5
- FirebirdClientDll 3.0.0.0

I'm (still) trying to access my legacy database with the Entity Framework (Code First).

Now I want to create a one to may relationship without a Forrein Key.

```
public class KONTAKTE
{
    public int KUNDENNR { get; set; }
    public Int16 ANSPRNR { get; set; }
    public Int16 NR { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<KONTAKTBED> KONTAKTBED { get; set; }
}
public class KONTAKTBED
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Int16 LFDNR { get; set; }
    public int KUNDENNR { get; set; }
    public Int16 ANSPRNR { get; set; }

    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```

public class CTKontakt : DbContext
    {

```
    public DbSet<KONTAKTE> KONTAKTE { get; set; }
    public DbSet<KONTAKTBED> KONTAKTBED { get; set; }

    public CTKontakt(DbConnection connectionString) : base(connectionString, false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CTKontakt>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

       /* modelBuilder.Entity<KONTAKTE>().
        HasMany(p => p.KONTAKTBED).
        WithMany().
        Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("KUNDENNR", "NR")
            .MapRightKey("KUNDENNR", "LFDNR"));*/ //Does't work

        modelBuilder.Entity<KONTAKTE>().HasKey(a => new { a.KUNDENNR, a.ANSPRNR, a.NR });     
        modelBuilder.Entity<KONTAKTBED>().HasKey(a => new { a.ID, a.DATABASE_ID});  

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

As you can see I can't use the whole Primary Key of the KONTAKTE-Table. Does this mean I have to implemet a many to many realitonship? Currently I just join the tables later:

```
from k in lEKontakt.KONTAKTE
join kbed in lEKontakt.KONTAKTBED
on new { KUNDENNR = k.KUNDENNR, NR = k.NR }
equals new { KUNDENNR = kbed.KUNDENNR, NR = kbed.LFDNR }
```

I want to do something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<KONTAKTE>()
.HasKey(d => new { d.KUNDENNR, d.ANSPRNR, d.NR })
.HasMany(d => d.KONTAKTBED)
.WithOptional()
.HasForeignKey(l => new { l.KUNDENNR, l.ANSPRNR, l.LFDNR });
```

But without the ANSPRNR...

I'm still new to Ef-Code First and all samples I find seem not to work under EF 5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for me:

It semms I only had to Remove the Primary Key definiton of the not used Field. I can still read the Data without it:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<KONTAKTE>()
            .HasRequired(b => b.KUNDEN)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.KUNDENNR);

        modelBuilder.Entity<KONTAKTE>()
        .HasKey(d => new { d.KUNDENNR, d.NR })
        .HasMany(d => d.KONTAKTBED)
        .WithOptional()
        .HasForeignKey(l => new { l.KUNDENNR, l.LFDNR });

        modelBuilder.Entity<KONTAKTE>().HasKey(a => new { a.KUNDENNR, a.NR });     

        modelBuilder.Entity<KUNDEN>().HasKey(a => new { a.KUNDENNR });

        modelBuilder.Entity<KONTAKTBED>().HasKey(a => new { a.ID, a.DATABASE_ID});  

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```